# How to neglect the '|' in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey I'm new to PHP and Codeigniter.

This is my controller code. Here I append '|' to each value. If I have no value in name3 and value3 then I don't append the '|' character. How do I check this, and insert it?

**controller**

```
       function event()
       {
        $event_name=$this->input->post('e_name'); 
        $unit1=$this->input->post('unit1');
        $unit2=$this->input->post('unit2');
        $unit3=$this->input->post('unit3');
        $unit4=$this->input->post('unit4');
        $value1=$this->input->post('value1');
        $v_unit1=$value1.'|'.$unit1;

        $name2=$this->input->post('name2');
        $value2=$this->input->post('value2');
        $v_unit2=$value2.'|'.$unit2;

        $name3=$this->input->post('name3');
        $value3=$this->input->post('value3');
        $v_unit3=$value3.'|'.$unit3;

        $name4=$this->input->post('name4');
        $value4=$this->input->post('value4');
        $v_unit4=$value4.'|'.$unit4;

        $event_data=array(
           'event_name'=>$event_name,
           'name1'=>$name1,
           'value1'=>$v_unit1,
           'name2'=>$name2,
           'value2'=>$v_unit2,
           'name3'=>$name3,
           'value3'=>$v_unit3,
           'name4'=>$name4,
           'value4'=>$v_unit4,
       );

       $this->home_model->insert_event($event_data);
       }
```

In my output I get '|' if I haven't entered the data. I want Null value to be entered in the database.

If the value exists then the data will be in this format: for e.g. 22 as value and kg as unit it should be formatted as `22|kg`, if no value is entered I get '|'. This my problem.

Comment: You will have to do a check if the data has been entered, and only then add your stuff to the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it using `!empty` as

```
$v_unit1 = (!empty($unit1) && !empty($value1)) ? $value1.'|'.$unit1 : '';
```

This'll check whether the variable is `isset` along with its not `empty` too

Comment: how do i prevent the occurance of '|' this character in the value field during codeigniter validation?

Comment: Sorry I can't get you but if its a new question you can simply ask new question . Thanks